# The "div" element was not closed. All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

keep getting on line 25 `<div id="ajaxDiv">`

> The "div" element was not closed.  All element must be either
>   self-closing or have a matching end tag.

any ideas why? none of the other answers on SO have worked for me.

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Vote

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Match";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>



<div>



    @Ajax.BeginForm("submitVote", "vote", new AjaxOptions
    {

        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "ajaxDiv"

    }
)
</div>



<div id="ajaxDiv">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Vote</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celeb1ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celeb1ID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celeb1ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celeb2ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celeb2ID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celeb2ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celeb1Votes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celeb1Votes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celeb1Votes)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celeb2Votes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celeb2Votes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celeb2Votes)
    </div>

    <p>


</fieldset>

<button type="submit" id="submitVote" name="button" value="v1">Vote Celeb 1</button>
<button type="submit" id="submitVote" name="button" value="v2">Vote Celeb 2</button>
</fieldset>

    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Is that an extra `</fieldset>` element you have there?

Comment: Sometimes when you have unclosed/incomplete tags this error occurs. It doesn't necessarily have to correspond to a `<div>` tag.

Comment: Mixing html and code not in server tags? Missing a `;`?

Comment: I removed the extra feildset and now get the error  Expected a "{" but found a "<".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages.

Comment: @zerkey, sorry i dont understand your reply.

Comment: Solved it thanks guys. It was a combination of the wrong tags, and i needed to put the feildset in {} brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the second `</fieldset>` near to `</div>`. It is messing up your tags.
2. And **also** close the `<p>` tag you have above the wrong `</fieldset>` tag.